# Change frame size of table programmatically

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview, ios8, xcode6.3

I am trying to do the example on https://github.com/kingiol/XCMultiSortTableView 
 where I am putting json values. I used navigational bar but then the header data is getting hidden. I tried changing the frame size in XCMultiSortTableView.m file but the position of header doesn't change. I am getting output as

[image]

But I want the output where years is displayed along with navigational bar as

[image]

Please do reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the topHeaderScrollView to

```
topHeaderScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(leftHeaderWidth + boldSeperatorLineWidth, 30, superWidth - leftHeaderWidth - boldSeperatorLineWidth, topHeaderHeight);
```

and changed the default header height to

```
#define XCMultiTableView_DefaultTopHeaderHeight 110.0f
```

Now I can view my header even when I have a navigation bar.